# Spring Data Search Entity Field - Query by example

Tags: java, spring-data

Does query by example allow you to do lessThan() , greaterThan() for integer type.

Comment: I think there's too little information in your question to generate meaningful answers.

Try to describe as precisely as possible what you are trying to achieve. Give a concrete Java code example that illustrates what you tried so far. Then describe what results you expected to get from the code and what actual results you got instead. Also describe what your reasoning behind the code example was.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring JPA Provide `lessThan()`, `greaterThan()` for integer type Columns as below. (eg:UserProfile findByAgeGreaterThan(Integer age))

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserProfile, String> {
   List<UserProfile> findByUsername(String username);
   UserProfile findByUserid(Integer user_id);
   UserProfile findByDevicesimno(String devicesimno);
   **UserProfile findByAgeGreaterThan(Integer age);**
}
```

For reference , please have a look on this https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation